# Submitting a form with a POST request after Facebook login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to log a user into the website with Facebook. I use the Facebook Javascript SDK to get a token which is sent to the API using Node.js for user login. I use a hidden form within the button to post that token. Right now the user clicks on the "login with facebook" button. It shows that their profile is logged in and collects their facebook token (putting it in the hidden form), then they press a submit button which submits their profile and token with a POST to the API.

The form looks like this:

```
<form id="fbForm" action="/FBLogin" method="post">
  <fb:login-button 
     scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"
     data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" 
     data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true">
  </fb:login-button>
  <input type="hidden" name="fbtokeninput" />

  <button type="submit">Login with Facebook</button>
</form>
```

The Facebook app login with the javascript sdk is as follows (but without the `form.submit()` line):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});

function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
}

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);

if (response.status === 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        console.log(response);

        var fbtoken = response.authResponse.accessToken
        document.getElementById('fbtokeninput').value = fbtoken;

        setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById("fbForm").submit();}, 1000);
    });
} else {
    //error message
}
```

}

Right now this works fine, but I don't want users to have to click on the second "submit" button to login. My main question is with the `setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById("fbForm").submit();}, 1000);` line. This doesn't work, and just the regular submit line without the delay doesn't work either.

How do you properly submit/POST this type of form to the API with javascript?

Comment: I am not sure putting the FB login button _inside_ of the form is a good idea - that button gets replaced with other elements, so not sure whether it might “damage” the form somehow. I’d try and put that FB button outside of the form first, and see if that changes things.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t actually have a form (with input fields and whatnot), so don´t try to submit one. Instead, just use an AJAX POST request ([fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), ...) to submit the Token to your server.